# Cannot provision an actuator in IoT Agent Fiware

Tags: mqtt, fiware, provisioning, fiware-orion

I am using the following python code to create a service group

```
import json
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:4041/iot/services'
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json", 'fiware-service': "openiot", 'fiware-servicepath': "/mtp"}

data = {
 "services": [
   {
     "apikey":      "456dgffdg56465dfg",
     "cbroker":     "http://orion:1026",
     "entity_type": "Door",
     #resource attribute is left blank since HTTP communication is not being used
     "resource":    ""
   }
 ]
}
res = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
#print(res.status_code)

if res.status_code == 201:
    print("Created")

elif res.status_code == 409:
    print("A resource cannot be created because it already exists")

else:
    print (res.raise_for_status())
```

But when trying to provision an actuator I get a bad request 400 error with the code below:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices'
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json", 'fiware-service': "openiot", 'fiware-servicepath': "/mtp"}

data = {
 "devices": [
    {
      "device_id": "door003",
      "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Door:door003",
      "entity_type": "Door",
      "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-UltraLight",
      "transport": "MQTT",
      "commands": [
        {"name": "unlock","type": "command"},
        {"name": "open","type": "command"},
        {"name": "close","type": "command"},
        {"name": "lock","type": "command"}
       ],
       "attributes": [
        {"object_id": "s", "name": "state", "type":"Text"}
       ]
    }
  ]
}

res = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
#print(res.status_code)

if res.status_code == 201:
    print("Created")

elif res.status_code == 409:
    print("Entity cannot be created because it already exists")

else:
    print (res.raise_for_status())
```

Here is the error message I get in console.

```
iot-agent            | time=2021-02-17T11:39:44.132Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=16f27639-49c2-4419-a926-2433805dbdb3 | trans=16f27639-49c2-4419-a926-2433805dbdb3 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.GenericMiddlewares | from=n/a | srv=smartdoor | subsrv=/mtp | msg=Error [BAD_REQUEST] handling request: Request error connecting to the Context Broker: 501 | comp=IoTAgent
iot-agent            | time=2021-02-17T11:39:44.133Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=390f5530-f537-4efa-980a-890a44153811 | trans=390f5530-f537-4efa-980a-890a44153811 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DomainControl | from=n/a | srv=smartdoor | subsrv=/mtp | msg=response-time: 29 | comp=IoTAgent
```

What is strange is that if a remove the commands from the payload the device provisioning works fine. Is there something am I doing wrong while trying to provision an actuator (not a sensor)?

IoT Agent version:

```
{"libVersion":"2.14.0-next","port":"4041","baseRoot":"/","version":"1.15.0-next"}
```

Orion version:

```
{
"orion" : {
  "version" : "2.2.0",
  "uptime" : "0 d, 0 h, 59 m, 18 s",
  "git_hash" : "5a46a70de9e0b809cce1a1b7295027eea0aa757f",
  "compile_time" : "Thu Feb 21 10:28:42 UTC 2019",
  "compiled_by" : "root",
  "compiled_in" : "442fc4d225cf",
  "release_date" : "Thu Feb 21 10:28:42 UTC 2019",
  "doc" : "https://fiware-orion.rtfd.io/en/2.2.0/"
}
}
```

My docker-compose file looks as follows:

```
iot-agent:
    image: fiware/iotagent-ul:latest
    hostname: iot-agent
    container_name: iot-agent
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
        - mongo-db
    networks:
        - default
    expose:
        - "4041"
    ports:
        - "4041:4041"
    environment:
        - IOTA_CB_HOST=orion
        - IOTA_CB_PORT=1026
        - IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4041
        - IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb
        - IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
        - IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true
        - IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2
        - IOTA_AUTOCAST=true
        - IOTA_MONGO_HOST=mongo-db
        - IOTA_MONGO_PORT=27017
        - IOTA_MONGO_DB=iotagentul
        - IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://iot-agent:4041
        - IOTA_MQTT_HOST=mosquitto
        - IOTA_MQTT_PORT=1883
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Orion version 2.2.0 is over *two years old* - try swapping it out and using the latest version. A 501 error usually indicates a problem on the server so maybe it is a bug on the entity data upsert which has been fixed.

Comment: It works fine after using the Context Broker latest version. Thanks for your help and your time Jason. By the way the last IoT Agent webinar was excellent.